# Displaying data with php depending on what is selected in select option

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to display data of the current selected option, from `mysql` using `php` only?. So my `select option` works fine and it displays good results. But I want 2 other `form-group` `divs` to display data depending on what is currently selected in `select option`. Is that possible using `php` only or is `javascript` necessary?

Html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="naslov">Naslov</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="naslov" name="naslov" value="<?php echo $titedit; ?>">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="oglas">Sadržaj</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="oglas" name="oglas" rows="5" ><?php echo $contedit; ?></textarea>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("db.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$title = $row['title'];
$mxnr = mysqli_num_rows('$query');


if ($mxnr > 0) {

    echo '<select class="form-control">';

    $counter = 1;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


        if($counter == 1){
            echo '<option ' . ($counter == 1 ? 'selected' : '') . ' value="opt' . $counter . '">' . $row["id"] . '. ' . $row["title"] . '</option>';
            $titedit = $row['title'];
            $contedit = $row['content'];

        }else{
            echo '<option value="opt' . $counter . '">' . $row["id"] . '. ' . $row["title"] . '</option>';
        }

        $counter++;

    }

    echo '</select>';

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need javascript for that, since PHP loads before everything else, you can use JQuery to change the divs when you select something making it interactive and responsive.

If i may add my opinion, rely on javascript, its really usefull most of the time and will help you a lot. Consider JQuery.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for answering. :)